# Correct access to TextEdit from another C# form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

there are 3 forms MainForm(), Form1(MainForm()), Form2(), in Form 1 the MainForm is passed through the constructor, I need to update TextEdit Form1() from Form2(). I made an empty Form1 constructor that does not accept any parameters, I tried it in 2 ways through a function and directly accessing textEdit. I get an error

> "System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference does not point to an instance of an >object."

In the code it looks like this: in Form1():

```
 public Form1()
            {
               public void UpdateTextBox()
                {
                    searchTextEdit.LostFocus += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)searchTextEdit.EditValue) && !searchSimpleButton.Focused)
                        {
                            searchTextEdit.Focus();
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
```

Form2():
`new Form1().UpdateTextBox()`
a similar error occurs when calling the searchTextEdit itself:
`new Form1().searchTextEdit.Focus();`
Please help me put the focus in TextEdit from Form2() correctly when called in Form1(), thanks.

I tried to implement it in the following way in Form1:

```
private Form2 _form2;

public Form1(Form2 form)
        {
            _form2 = form;
           public void UpdateTextBoxt()
            {
                searchTextEdit.LostFocus += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)searchTextEdit.EditValue) && !searchSimpleButton.Focused)
                    {
                        searchTextEdit.Focus();
                    }
                };
            }
        }
```

Form2:

```
new Form2(this).UpdateTextBoxt();
```

Same error, am I missing something somewhere. Please help me

Comment: If you try to reference the Forms among them, you introduce dependencies, which you may want to avoid. So, what you actually need is a means to communicate. In WinForms, a common approach would be Events. So, you could share a common "EventSource" object, that may be static or ctor-injected, so all of the Forms can register for events on it and also make it fire events.

Comment: @Fildor I have not encountered a similar task before, could you show me on my example how this can be implemented? There are no similar questions in the search. I beg you to help me, thank you

Comment: Btw: Why do nest `UpdateTextBox()` in the ctor? That doesn't make sense. `searchTextEdit`might not even be initialized, yet.

Comment: @Fildor I didn’t have similar tasks before, so out of desperation I invent unnecessary actions (

Comment: OK. So, first of all: Forms should include a method `InitializeComponents()` that is usually the first line in the Ctor. It is most likely auto-created by the template and ensures all compoments for the form are instanciated and configured. Only after that is done, you can access the references without getting NullReferenceException.

Comment: Then: What it seems to me you are trying to do, is some kind of Input-Validation (searchTextEdit must be filled with text if another button is not in focus) , right. This is to be found in many tutorials and even by microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-keyboard/validation?view=netdesktop-6.0

Comment: Now, I am still not sure what the relation between Form1 and Form2 is. What do they do? Or better: What are they supposed to do?

Comment: @Fildor I need to always set focus and keyboard input in a TextEdit from one form by clicking any of the buttons on another

Comment: @Fildor I will give an example on the form 1 there are 7 buttons and a dialog box. When displaying a dialog box in form 1 and after pressing the "yes" or "no" button, it is necessary that the focus returns to the TextEdit from form 2 permanently and keyboard input can be performed. You can help me implement this functionality, please